# Ionic - Print receipt with thermal printer through LAN/WiFi

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm developing a POS app with Ionic 3. Currently, I need to print a receipt with a thermal printer through LAN/WiFi/USB. Does anyone has any idea how to do this?

I have checked https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/printer/, but it doesn't provide printing through network for Android. Also, the company provides a SDK, but as I know I cannot use it with ionic..

Comment: Looks like no such support yet...

Comment: Do you have a working example?

Comment: No, I don't.. Still looking.

Comment: did you find the solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: Sadly, not yet.. though I haven't really worked on this project for sometime. Please let me know if you find it..

Comment: [shanthan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6599228) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66492295) saying "we can do it by this plugin https://github.com/blocshop/sockets-for-cordova demo - https://github.com/Ans0n-Ti0/esc-pos-encoder-ionic-demo"